# python elementtree - how to find all elements in xml with certain attribute

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have xml in similiar structure:

```
<terms>
    <entry ID="1">
        <language ID="1">en</language>
        <term>user</term>
        <state>text</state>
        <use>text</use>
        <definition ID="1">text</definition>
            <subdefinition ID="1">text</subdefinition>
        <definition-source>text</definition-source>
        <source ID="1">text</source>
        <circle>text</circle>
    </entry>
```

In this case, parent and child elements contain attribute ID. Is there a way, how to find all elements from a tree that contains attribute ID and change value to 0 or dele it?

I was trying to do it with XPath but it's difficult when there is a deep hierarchy and any of elements can have this attribute.
another way would be to handle it as a string, but is there a way how to do it in ElementTree?

Comment: You should have a look at this: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be fairly easy using the XPath `.//*[@ID]` to select the elements.

Here's an example changing all `ID` values to `0`...

**XML Input** (test.xml)

```xml
<terms>
    <entry ID="1">
        <language ID="1">en</language>
        <term>user</term>
        <state>text</state>
        <use>text</use>
        <definition ID="1">text</definition>
            <subdefinition ID="1">text</subdefinition>
        <definition-source>text</definition-source>
        <source ID="1">text</source>
        <circle>text</circle>
    </entry>
</terms>
```

**Python**

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("test.xml")

for elem in tree.findall(".//*[@ID]"):
    elem.attrib["ID"] = "0"

ET.dump(tree.getroot())
```

**Output** (dumped to console)

```xml
<terms>
    <entry ID="0">
        <language ID="0">en</language>
        <term>user</term>
        <state>text</state>
        <use>text</use>
        <definition ID="0">text</definition>
            <subdefinition ID="0">text</subdefinition>
        <definition-source>text</definition-source>
        <source ID="0">text</source>
        <circle>text</circle>
    </entry>
</terms>
```