# Find values of specific parameters from XML

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71242297/xml-find-elements-by-tag-using-python-and-print-to-console) approach but it doesn't work for me.

I want to get the releaseDate value from the below xml

```
<Product prodID="bed" lang="en"> 
<ProductState stateType="Published" stateDateTime="2019-04" testDate="2019-04" releaseDate="2019"/>
```

I have tried the below code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import tempfile
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlfile = 'path_to_xml'
tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()

for elm in root.findall("./Product/ProductStatus/releaseDate"):
    print(elm.attrib)
```

Answer (score 1):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: xml.etree.ElementTree - The ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree).
Considering this **exact** *XML* blob, there are 2 errors in your code:

- The root node is *Product* node, so if you search for (other) *Product* sub-nodes it won't find anything
- *releaseDate* is an **attribute** (**not** a tag) so it doesn't belong in the path

Here''s an example.

*blob.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Product prodID="bed" lang="en"> 
    <ProductState stateType="Published" stateDateTime="2019-04" testDate="2019-04" releaseDate="2019"/>
    <!-- Other nodes -->
</Product>
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def main(*argv):
    xmlfile = "./blob.xml"
    root = ET.parse(xmlfile).getroot()
    print("Root node:", root)
    for product_state_node in root.findall("ProductState"):
        print("Release date: ", product_state_node.attrib.get("releaseDate"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q074401612]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Root node: <Element 'Product' at 0x0000020698C4A860>
> Release date:  2019
>
> Done.
> ```

Although for this simple example it's might not be the case I prefer *XPath* when iterating *XML* trees. For more details you could check (there are many more):

- [[SO]: get attribute of and iter only with elementTree (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72586651/4788546)
- [[SO]: Parsing XML by specifying name of child where multiple exist (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71929694/4788546)
- [[SO]: parsing some XML fields to text file in python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59060186/4788546)

Answer (score 0):

With `.get("attributeName")` you can ask for the attribute value of your interest `tag`.

If you change your code to:

```
for elm in root.findall("ProductState"):
    print(elm.get("releaseDate"))
```

it will work, if `Product` is your root.

```
print(elm.attrib) # prints all attributes as a dic of key:values
```